# How to keep a raw string (as a variable) so that I can pass it to a function?

Tags: python

I'm using firebase, which stores images with special characters, like so `https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/myapp.appspot.com/o/images%2F2021%2F5%2F600_jpgimage_5.jpg?generation=1620831628595831&alt=media`

But I want to pass this image to Pillow to do some functions, using `img = Image.open(requests.get(imageURL, stream=True).raw)` etc.

But when I log the string that is being passed, it's been transformed to `https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/myapp.appspot.com/o/images/2021/5/600_jpgimage_5.jpg?generation=1620831628595831`

I have tried doing this `rawStringURL = r'%s' %request_args["url"]` (this URL is being passed as an argument in Google Cloud Functions which uses Flask).

How can I keep this URL so that when I perform operations on it in Pillow, it will work? Should I download it to a /temp folder first perhaps?

I'm very new to Python, having written most of my app in JavaScript.

Comment: Aren't both of the urls equivalent though? `%2F` is  the escape sequence for `/`. You may wish to look into `urllib.parse.quote()` and `urllib.parse.unquote()`.

Comment: If you paste in the string that's transformed, google storage gives you an error

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the issue - still needs testing but working for now

`import urllib.parse`

`url = request_args["URL"] #request being received by the Google Cloud Function (Flask)`

```
    url = request_args["url"]
    url_first_half = url[0:89]
    url_second_half = url[89:]
    split_url = url_second_half.split("?")
    url_to_encode = split_url[0]
    url_end = split_url[1]]
    encoded_url_middle = urllib.parse.quote(
        url_to_encode, safe='%20', encoding=None, errors=None)
    correct_url = url_first_half + encoded_url_middle + "?" + url_end + "&alt=media"
```